# Solar Plane, Voltage drop when under a load

Tags: solar-cell

This is a project with a group of high school kids who want to be engineers.  The students have built a solar power airplane.  We are using maxeon solar cells.

Here is a link to the test video from yesterday.  Notice the voltage drop when we start the motor.  The cells are rated at .58v (Vmpp) at 6amps (Impp).

Some of the cells have minor damage due to this being a group of high school kids, so that could very well be contributing to the problem.

Here is the video, any thoughts.
[Static Run Up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvA08SGm2iU)

Comment: Linking to a video in your question is generally not recommended; it's better that you describe what you saw and why you think it's a problem.

Comment: Yeah, but then someone who wishes to see the problem or the data can see the video evidence to help devise an appropriate answer to the question.  I think in this case the video is appropriate.

Comment: Perhaps so, but consider people who, for one reason or another, can't watch the video. Maybe they're deaf, maybe they're blind, maybe they're simply busy and can't spend however long the video is watching a video, but have a few seconds to read some text.

Comment: What's the current draw? What's the impedance of the cells? What's the volt drop in numbers? Have you applied V=IR?

Comment: Do you have any link to the cell datasheet ? .58v seems a little high for voltage at max power for silicon cells. Also : do you have an estimate of the cell temperature ? Voltage decreases as temperature increases.

Comment: Power seems to max out at about 45watts.  The system should be capable of 17.5volts * 6amps = 105watts .  Each cell is rated at 3.49w (Pmpp) when under a load.

Comment: https://us.sunpower.com/sites/sunpower/files/media-library/spec-sheets/sp-sunpower-maxeon-solar-cells-gen2.pdf

Comment: Did you apply „positive electrical grounding“ as stated in the datasheet? It says that if you did not, there will be reduced power.

Comment: no, we did not positive ground this system...the cells are connected in series, positive side to negative side just like connecting batteries in series.  At the end of the series of cells we then have a positive lead and a negative lead which are directly connected to the engine speed control, just as if the solar cells made up a battery.  We do have a diode installed between the solar cells and the battery to prevent current from flowing from the battery to the cells.

Comment: I am not sure where we would ground to...The airplane is EPO foam.  So how could the electrical system be positive ground in our application?

Comment: Not gonna watch a video.  All pertinent information to a question needs to be in the question.  This question is *unclear* in its present form.

Comment: It depends on the type of diode, but if its standard (Vf = 1V) you might loose 6Watts at 6 Amps. I think its a good thing to remove that extra diode!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some of the cells have minor damage due to this being a group of high school kids, so that could very well be contributing to the problem.

Very much so! A solar cell is basically a current source shunted by a diode (the latter is what determines Voc). If a damaged (or shaded) cell has a lower maximum current, it limits the current through the entire string, which has a huge effect on Pmax.

Test the cells individually (just connect an ammeter directly across each one), and eliminate any that can't deliver the full 6A.

Comment: Totally think that you are correct.  That was my guess.  This was an incredable project to learn from.  Myself and the students learned a ton from this project.  I so look forward to revising the design and moving onto Solar Plane V2...thank you!